# Authentication for Azure Mobile Web Services test pages

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

When developing a Azure Mobile Service I can run the test page when running locally. If I press the 'try it out' button i can test my api, but when published to Azure I need to authenticate to use the 'try it out' button.

My question is what is the username and password for the test page when published to the cloud? I haven't specified any authorization in my project afaik.

Comment: try empty or any username, and use the application key as the password

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use either the application key or the master key as password -- the username doesn't matter. You can get both keys from the portal by selecting a mobile service and then "Manage Keys" at the bottom of the page.

Thanks,

Henrik

Comment: how do I get the application key after hosting in IIS Manager?